# Admob with firebase, only view ads: Nice job! You're displaying a 320x50 test ad from admob

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I add admob for my app as guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLLLRUPICcc&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIKX0pUJV3uqp6N3NeHwHh0c&index=1&spfreload=5

But admob is only view:
Nice job! You're displaying a 320x50 test ad from admob

It does NOT change other ads. Please help me.

**Code as below:**

In activity at onCreate:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-9518053516260440/6844465750");
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

in xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Acording to the Quickstart

> If you haven't created an AdMob account and registered an app yet,
>   there's no better time than now. If you're just experimenting with the
>   SDK in a Hello World app, though, you can use this App ID to call the
>   initialize method: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713.

You are using testing appID. To make it work you need to create your own account. Than create application and use your own application ID. This will let you customize what ads should show and it will show actual ads. But for testing you should use this AppID, because you should not click on your own ads.

Fix your appID in xml. But even then it takes some time to actualy start working. It might take about day to start showing real ads.